# What are these files in my /dev directory?

Tags: filesystem, files, c, devices

I know that most devices are presented in the `/dev` directory, but only now have I actually noticed two very strange, yet familiar names in there...

I'm talking about `stdin@` and `stdout@` down there:

[image]

What are these for? Are they used by functions of the C language?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These files are actually called `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`. The `@` character is added by `ls` to tell you that they are [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). `ls -l` would reveal that the targets of these symbolic links are `/proc/self/fd/0`, `/proc/self/fd/1` and `/proc/self/fd/2`.

[`/proc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) is a virtual filesystem provided by the kernel that shows information about the operating system. Among other things, there are directories like `/proc/1234` that contain information about the process with ID 1234. `/proc/self` is a symbolic link to the directory for whatever process is accessing it (the kernel returns a different target to different processes).

`/proc/self/fd` (which is also symlinked at `/dev/fd`) contains one entry per file that the process has open. Each entry corresponds to a file descriptor and is a symbolic link to the file (if possible — for pipes, sockets and deleted files, the symbolic link gives information that's useful for debugging but does not point to a file that you could reopen by name). These file descriptors are the same that you manipulate with C functions such as `open`, `close`, `dup`, `read`, `write`, etc. They are not *used by* the C functions, they're other ways to interact with the same objects.

The reason `/dev/stdin` and friends exist is that sometimes a program requires a file name, but you want to tell it to use a file that's already open (a pipe, for instance). So you can pass `/dev/stdin` to tell the program to read its standard input.

Further reading:

- [file descriptor vs. file name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18258/file-descriptor-vs-file-name)
- [file descriptors and /dev/fd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26926/file-descriptors-and-dev-fd)
- [How does /dev/fd relate to /proc/self/fd/?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18255/how-does-dev-fd-relate-to-proc-self-fd)
- [Understanding /dev and its subdirs and files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18239/understanding-dev-and-its-subdirs-and-files)
- [How to include program which only works with in/out files into a pipeline?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40210/how-to-include-program-which-only-works-with-in-out-files-into-a-pipeline)